# AppleScript : Adding multiple cells of different columns to only one selection range in Numbers

Tags: applescript

I'm new to Stack Overflow and relatively new to Applescript.
I managed to set some cell values to 0 using two selection range in a row to do it.

I couldn't find a solution to create a customized selection range allowing the selection of all these cells in one.

Here's my code :

```
tell table "Add"
            set selection range to range ("B2:B3")
            set the value of cell of selection range to "0"
            set selection range to range ("D2:D5")
            set the value of cell of selection range to "0"
end tell
```

How could I have one selection range with ("B2:B3" & "D2:D5")?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: I don't think that Numbers.app lets applescript make complex selections. If you 'get' the two ranges then it uses the top left/bottom right cells to make the range (i.e. "B2:D5"). Out of curiosity, why do you want to select two ranges simultaneously?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I need it to reset multiple cells after a selection.
I have multiple checkbox columns once selected  add a row on another sheet(with a script).
When I need to create another row of data I want the checkbox to set to 0 first.... That's  why :)

Comment: What I mean is… if you know the ranges in advance (as in your example) then you could just set the values of the cells. Even your 4 lines could be reduced to two with: set the value of the cells of range "B2:B3" to "0". So is controlling a complex selection still necessary?

Comment: Yess thank you it's much better ! :D

Comment: Glad to hear. If you want a more general control you could reset the values of checkboxes inside a given range. (Replace each semi-colon with a return) : set cbRange to range "B2:D5"; set cbCells to cells of cbRange whose format is checkbox; repeat with a in cbCells; set value of a to false; end repeat;

Comment: Great! thank you for all this good information Mockman.

Comment: I have an other question, is it possible in a script to add row in a document without the need to opening it ?
I tried to tell the document with his path but it doesn't work unless I opened it before...

Comment: You're welcome. I probably should have put it in an answer but I wasn't clear on your objective. As to writing to unopened files… technically, that functionality exists. Realistically, it isn't something you can casually do with an xls document (or any file stored as binary data). It is relatively straightforward with text files (including csv), using commands like 'open for access'. It could likely be done with an xlsx doc but I'm not familiar enough with that format to know with certainty.

Comment: ok because i tried to export in csv just one sheet of my number document but it doesn't work so I created an other document with the adding row from the script(to be able to export only this sheet) so I don't need it to be open but it doesn't really matter.. thanks !

Comment: That's a weird thing that you can't export a single sheet (at least not with Numbers 5). You could also try to export all the sheets as CSV and then move the extraneous ones to the trash.

Comment: I use number version 10.1 and yes i could do that too but i want to use it on a daily basis so move 1 csv every time to the trash... I will see if I can find a solution to it, thanks for all Mockman !